# Specialising a templated function for a templated (Armadillo) class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, armadillo

I'm trying to put together a very simple logging class which treats certain types, and particularly vectors, specially. I want to have a default behaviour when using the `<<` operator, but modify it in certain cases. The set-up is:

```
class LoggerStream
{
    template <typename ArgType>
    LoggerStream & operator<< (const ArgType &arg)
    {
        // Standard logging logic
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename DataType>
    LoggerStream & operator<< (const std::vector<DataType> &arg)
    {
        // Specialised logging logic
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename DataType>
    LoggerStream & operator<< (const arma::Col<DataType> &arg)
    {
        // Specialised logging logic
        return *this;
    }

    LoggerStream & operator<< (const double &arg)
    {
        // Specialised logging logic
        return *this;
    }

    // Other stuff...
};
```

The `double` case works fine. The problem is that for *subclasses* of the vector types, the general-purpose template seems to take priority, and the more specific template gets ignored.

<strike>Since all three templated cases have just one generic template parameter I guess the the vector cases aren't considered the most specialised, but if it were considered ambiguous I would expect a compiler error. (It compiles just fine.) So how can I indicate a specialisation but still generalise over the type of the vector elements? Thanks in advance.</strike>

<strike>I guess this is to do with some detail of how the `Col` class is implemented. I'm using (and aliasing) `arma::Col<T>::fixed<N>` as well, but writing a specific overload for that doesn't seem to help. Any ideas welcome.</strike>

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8c49a513bdd5077). You'll need to show us a complete compilable example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Cannot reproduce that. Trying to guess, is your vector a `std::vector<T>` and not a `std::vector<T, special_alloc<T> >`?

Comment: Just to be clear, the vector version is an overload, too, not specialization.

Comment: Hmm. There's no special allocator here, nothing unusual as far as I know. I'll look further into it and follow up. Thanks for testing it.

Comment: Right, apologies. I hadn't realised that all my examples are actually `arma::Col` and not `std::vector`, so it's that case in particular that's problematic. I guess that makes this an Armadillo-specific question. I'll edit to reflect that. In the meantime, thanks for helping clarify that the problem is not a general misunderstanding on my part!

Comment: You may want to overload on arma::Mat<T> instead of arma::Col<T>. The latter inherits from the former. Alernatively, use a concrete type, such as Col<double>.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it. This code works as it is supposed to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class LoggerStream
{
public:
    template <typename ArgType>
    LoggerStream &operator<< (const ArgType &arg)
    {
        // Standard logging logic
        cout << "In general" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename DataType>
    LoggerStream &operator<< (const std::vector<DataType> &arg)
    {
        // Specialised logging logic
        cout << "In vector" << endl;

        return *this;
    }

};

int main()
{
    LoggerStream foo;
    vector<int> v;
    foo << v; // calling the vector specialization
}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking. This does indeed seem to be specific to `arma::Col`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question not because I have a resolution (yet), but to clarify the problem after further investigation. In fact this doesn't seem to be specific to `arma::Col`; rather, the issue seems to be in the precedence given to the more specific overload when the argument is of a subclass type. A simple example that shows the problem without using Armadillo is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename DataType>
class MyVector : public std::vector<DataType> {};

class LoggerStream
{
public:
    template <typename ArgType>
    LoggerStream &operator<< (const ArgType &arg)
    {
        cout << "In general" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename DataType>
    LoggerStream &operator<< (const std::vector<DataType> &arg)
    {
        cout << "In vector" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LoggerStream foo;
    std::vector<float> v;
    foo << v;  // Prints "In vector", as expected
    MyVector<float> w;
    foo << w;  // Prints "In general" (but only if the general case exists)
}
```

So, using the subclass `MyVector` produces a call to the general function, not the specialised one. But, if the first version is commented out then both calls produce "In vector". So for some reason both are deemed suitable, but the general function is preferred.

What I still don't know is how to stop this from happening without explicitly writing out a load of specific overloads for individual subclass cases...